# Flatten range pairs in Python (heapy/bisect?)

Tags: python, bioinformatics

In bioinformatics, we do the following transformation an awful lot:

```
>>> data = {
    (90,100):1,
    (91,101):1,
    (92,102):2,
    (93,103):1,
    (94,104):1
}

>>> someFuction(data)

{
     90:1,
     91:2,
     92:4,
     93:5,
     94:6,
     95:6,
     96:6,
     97:6,
     98:6,
     99:6,
    100:6,
    101:5,
    102:4,
    103:2,
    104:1
}
```

Where the tuple in data is always a unique pair.
But there are many methods for doing this transform - some significantly better than others. One i have tried is:

```
newData = {}
for pos, values in data.iteritems():
    A,B = pos
    for i in xrange(A,B+1):
        try: newData[i] += values
        except KeyError: newData[i] = values
```

This has the benefit that its short and sweet, but im not actually sure it is that efficient....
I have a feeling that somehow turning the dict into a list of lists, and then doing the xrange, would save an awful lot of time. We're talking weeks of computational work per experiment. Something like this:

```
>>> someFuction(data)
[ 
    [90,90,1], 
    [91,91,2], 
    [92,92,4], 
    [93,93,5], 
    [94,100,6], 
    [101,101,5], 
    [102,102,4], 
    [103,103,2], 
    [104,104,1] 
]
```

and THEN do the for/xrange loop.
People on #Python have recommended bisect and heapy, but after struggling with bisect all day, I can't come up with a nice algorithm which i can be 100% will work all the time. If anyone on here could help or even point me in the right direction, id be massively grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a solution last night that takes the total run time of one file from roughly 400 minutes to 251 minutes. I would post the code but its pretty long, and likely to have bugs in the edge-cases. For that reason i'll say the 'working' code can be found in the program 'rawSeQL', but the algorithmic improvements that helped the most were:

- Looping over the overlapping arrays and flattening them to non-overlapping arrays with a multiplier value made an enormous difference, as xrange() does not now need to repeat itself.
- Using collections.defaultdict(int) made a big difference over the try/except loop above. collections.Counter() and orderedDict was a LOT slower than the try/except.
- I went with using bisect_left() to find where to insert the next non-overlapping piece, and it was so-so, but then adding in Bisect's 'low' parameter to limit the range of the list it needs to check gave a sizeable reduction in compute time. If you sort the input list, your value for low is always the last returned value for bisect, which makes this process easy :)

It is possible that heapy would provide even more benefits still - but for now the main algorithm improvements mentioned above will probably outweigh any compile-time tricks. I have 75 files to process now, which means just these three things save roughly 12500 days of compute time :)